# CentOS7 で MySQL サーバを停止したい

Tags: mysql, centos

CentOS7でMySQL5.7を使用しています。

MySQLを全て停止したいのですが、停止してstatusを確認すると以下のようになり、停止できません。

```
# MySQLを停止
service mysqld stop

# statusを確認
service mysqld status
Aug 25 18:36:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Server...
Aug 25 18:36:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started MySQL Server.
Aug 25 18:42:54 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopping MySQL Server...
Aug 25 18:42:56 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
```

これらのステータスはどのようにすれば全て停止できますでしょうか？
またこれらが意味することは4つそれぞれ別のプロセスでMySQLサーバが立ち上がっているということでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3):

`status` の結果として表示された文章をちゃんと読みましたか？

MySQL サーバを開始（しようと）しています
MySQL サーバが開始しました
MySQL サーバを停止（しようと）しています
MySQL サーバが停止しました

# 要するに開始中や終了中にエラーが発生していないというログ

ってことで４つ別プロセスが上がっているとかそういう主張はここではなされていません。正しく終了している、つまり何一つ問題ないということのようです。

Comment: see also https://teratail.com/questions/287415

Answer (score 2):

`service` コマンドを実行されていますが、CentOS**7** からは `systemctl` に置き換えられています。
(service コマンドを実行しても systemctl コマンドにリダイレクトされる)

実際に実行すべきなのは、例えば以下のような書式になります。

```
$ sudo systemctl status mysqld.service
```

そして、`systemctl` を実行した時には **直近の動作ログ** の数行が表示されているので、末尾が `Stopped MySQL Server` になっているなら該当のプロセスは停止しています。

もしくは `systemctl status mysqld.service` を実行した際、`Active:` の行を見れば現在の状態が確認できます。

**動作中:**

```
  Active: active (running)
```

**停止中:**

```
  Active: inactive (dead)
```